# Does npm/yarn install devDependencies by default?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, dependencies, shared-libraries

I'm working on private library of react components. I've already setup the whole workflow etc. but I'm not sure about one thing.

In my library I have some packages listed as `peerDependencies` which have to be peer ones (for example `react`, cuz only one instance of react can be installed at once, otherwise everything breaks). But if I'd like to setup some tests in my library I need `react` installed there as `devDependency`.

So I have to install react as `peer` and `dev` in  library. And what happens when I publish this package to npm register? `devDependencies` are excluded here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you create a node package, and you have some dev dependencies, npm wont count them for the publish. That's why it's called `devDependencies`. It's not under the production code.

Answer (score 2):

If you need it in production, add it to `peerDependencies`. Otherwise, leave it in `devDependencies`. When someone installs your library, dev dependencies won't be installed, and peer dependencies should already be installed.

Answer (score 1):

I know you have to specify when installing an npm package --save-dev so it saves dependencies onto your json file.